# How to add an array of objects in JSON

Tags: json

My question is entirely related to the structure of JSON. I've this:

```
{
  "cars": {
    "rows": [
      {
        "name": "Mercedes",
        "color": "Black",
        "make": "Mercedes"
      },
      {
        "name": "BMW",
        "color": "Black",
        "make": "BMW Germany"
      },
      {
        "name": "Innova",
        "color": "Red",
        "make": "Toyota"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Till now, `row` is an array of objects that contains information of different cars. I want two such row arrays. Only two are required. Like this:

```
{
  "staticKpi": {
    "rows": [
      {
        // 1st row 1st object
      },
      {
        // 1st row 2nd object
      },
      {
        // 1st row 3rd object
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        // 2nd row 1st object
      },
      {
        // 2nd row 2nd object
      },
      {
        // 2nd row 3rd object
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can see this JSON [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.a5170697919c49c2aa347314a35171d2&right=local.zonara).
But this is giving me JSON error. I just want to keep two lines of objects so there will be only two arrays in `rows`. hope I was able to explain the problem. Please correct my mistake.

PS: I've run forEach loop later on this JSON. So I've to take care of that too.

Comment: Why not each items in `rows` being an array? This structure is invalid : `{ "rows": [ { } ],[ { } ] }`. However, this one is valid `{ "rows": [ [ {  } ], [ {  } ] ] }`

Comment: @Cid Will it support multiple objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```json
{
   "staticKpi":{
      "rows":[
         [
            {
               "name":"Mercedes",
               "color":"Black",
               "make":"Mercedes"
            },
            {
               "name":"BMW",
               "color":"Black",
               "make":"BMW Germany"
            },
            {
               "name":"Innova",
               "color":"Red",
               "make":"Toyota"
            }
         ],
         [
            {
               "name":"Mercedes",
               "color":"Black",
               "make":"Mercedes"
            },
            {
               "name":"BMW",
               "color":"Black",
               "make":"BMW Germany"
            },
            {
               "name":"Innova",
               "color":"Red",
               "make":"Toyota"
            }
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

`rows` needs to be one object/array, it can't be two. To have more than one element, you need to put those two elements in an array.

EDIT:
To loop through these using `forEach` in JavaScript, you could do this:

```js
data = {"staticKpi":{"rows":[[{"name":"Mercedes","color":"Black","make":"Mercedes"},{"name":"BMW","color":"Black","make":"BMW Germany"},{"name":"Innova","color":"Red","make":"Toyota"}],[{"name":"Mercedes","color":"Black","make":"Mercedes"},{"name":"BMW","color":"Black","make":"BMW Germany"},{"name":"Innova","color":"Red","make":"Toyota"}]]}};

data.staticKpi.rows.forEach((row) => console.log(row));
```

Comment: I just wonder how do i tweak forEach loop for this new structure. Please throw some light on this.

Comment: I've added to this answer an example of looping through the rows element (so that you get each of the two).

Comment: I just showed this answer to my tech lead. She said this solution is good and we can push it to master. thanks :-)